# Incorporate Unity application in a native Android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, import

I have a Unity Android application that just uses the native camera from the device and have proceeded to make some AR. I want to implement this app in an Android project where I have all my UI (drawer menu, splash screen, features, etc.).

Is this possible, or can I not mix a Unity app and Android native app?

Comment: Had found some answers to this problem but for IOS. Here is the link : http://www.makethegame.net/?s=Add+unity3d+to+native

Answer (score 0):

After some research, that's totally possible.

You can start an Unity activity into an android native activity. You need to export your Unity project into a library that you can use from your android project.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the Unity player activity with your own or you can plugin your own activity in tot he unity project.

The following piece of code is from a plugin that allows you to open up the Gallery as an activity. ( but you should be able to do something similar )

```
// @desc    UnityProxyActivity - This class is part of Native Galley and a subset of Camera Capture Kit for Unity. 
// @author  Tastybits 
// @link    www.tastybits.io | https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673 
public class UnityProxyActivity extends Activity {
static final String ACTION_FINISH = "com.Tastybits.ACTION_FINISH";
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Unity", "ProxyActivity: OnCreate");

    // Start a Gallery.....   
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_PICK );
    startActivityForResult( intent, 100 );
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if( AndroidGallery.OpenGallery_Callback!=null ) 
        AndroidGallery.OpenGalleryFireCallback( /*ok*/false, /*cancelled*/true, "" );
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        if( AndroidGallery.OpenGallery_Callback!=null ) 
            AndroidGallery.OpenGalleryFireCallback( /*ok*/false, /*cancelled*/true, "" );
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d( "Unity", "UnityProxyActivity: onActivityResult(" + requestCode + ", " + resultCode + ", " + data);

    this.finish();

    if( requestCode == 100 ) {

        try {

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String spath = getRealPathFromURI(uri); //uri.getPath();
            if( AndroidGallery.OpenGallery_Callback!=null ) 
                AndroidGallery.OpenGalleryFireCallback( /*ok*/true, /*cancelled*/false, "file://"+spath );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            Log.d("Unity","UnityProxyActivity - caught unknown exception");
            if( AndroidGallery.OpenGallery_Callback!=null ) 
                AndroidGallery.OpenGalleryFireCallback( /*ok*/false, /*cancelled*/false, "" );
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("Unity", "NativeGallery: Unknown requestCode " + requestCode );   
    }


}}
```

You would then have to start the activity by something like

```
Intent i = new Intent(UnityPlayer.currentActivity,com.NativeGallery.UnityProxyActivity.class);
    UnityPlayer.currentActivity.startActivity(i);
```

The following is an example on how an activity is started from the Unity app. You should be able to replace it with your own code or if you want to do it the other way around- starting the unity activity from your activity you would have to build a unity android project and extend upon that.

Cheers!